# Business audit events on Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, audit-trail, audit-logging

I have some **spring-boot** micro-services deployed on **Cloud Foundry** and I have to implement propagation and storing (to a repository) the business audit events emitted by them.

I can do it in several ways, e.g.:

1. Publish audit events to a `Source` ([`Spring Cloud Stream`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) / RabbitMQ) and consume it by a `Sink` service writing the events to the repository.
2. Publish audit events as a custom application log and consume it by a [`log-consuming service`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/app-log-streaming.html) filtering and writing the events to the repository.
3. Publish audit events using `internal CF's mechanism` as a new custom [`log type`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#format) or a custom [`audit event`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/managing-cf/audit-events.html) - I think this option isn't a good idea but I can be wrong...

Is there any recommended approach/pattern to realize this issue on Cloud Foundry platform?

---

**EDIT**

All the approaches meet (in my opinion) the [12-factor](https://12factor.net/) rules, but each has its advantages and disadvantages:

- **(1) Spring Cloud Streams**

  - `+` ensures delivery (events will not be lost)
  - `+` allows to use routing (RabbitMQ)
  - `-` requires connection to a message broker (not as easy as a logger)
- **(2) log-consuming service**

  - `+` is easy
  - `-` logs can be lost
  - `-` audit biznes info is too widely propagated - [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)
- **(3) new CF's log type**

  - `-` probably forces changes in the CF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question with a question. What exactly are your "business audit logs"? Would there be a problem if you lost some of them?

If the answer is **yes** and it's unacceptable to lose even a single log then I would make the case that they're not really logs, but business records (that perhaps just look like logs). In this case, store the records in a database or other service where there is storage is guaranteed. It's extra work, but you need to make sure these records are properly stored so the extra effort is warranted.

If the answer is **no** and it's acceptable to lose some or even all (plan for worst case) of these logs, then I would suggest just writing them to STDOUT. Cloud Foundry will handle the routing of these logs for you, so it's super easy. You can bind a syslog drain if you want to send them to a log consuming service or you could implement a Loggregator Nozzle and read the logs directly from CF. From the app's perspective it doesn't really matter and you could even change your mind later and not need to update your app.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're right, these aren't logs, these are business events that I'm considering to propagate as logs (I just corrected the question). It's unacceptable to lose even a single event.
I realized that CF can't guarantee the delivery of logs to a log-consuming service because of nonblocking (to application) nature of loggregator and gRCP/UDP... 
BTW, where should `log-consuming service` be placed on this image https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/loggregator/images/architecture/loggregatornew.png ?

Comment: There's two possibilities. If your adding a syslog drain to your app then it is the bottom right where it says "Syslog Adapter". That feeds to your syslog service. If you are pulling logs directly from the firehose, then it's above that where it says "Nozzles". The examples are "Datadog" and "TSDB", which are firehoze nozzles. You could implement your own nozzle to read from there. It has some more capabilities, but it's also more work to implement a firehose nozzle though because it's specific to CF. The syslog drain works with any compatible syslog server/service.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I stick with [12 factor application](https://12factor.net) rules.

The 11th rule is: **[Treat logs as event streams](https://12factor.net/logs)**

This is the important part about logging:

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of
>   its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage
>   logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream,
>   unbuffered, to stdout. During local development, the developer will
>   view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the
>   app’s behavior.
>
> In staging or production deploys, each process’ stream will be
>   captured by the execution environment, collated together with all
>   other streams from the app, and routed to one or more final
>   destinations for viewing and long-term archival. These archival
>   destinations are not visible to or configurable by the app, and
>   instead are completely managed by the execution environment.
>   Open-source log routers (such as Logplex and Fluentd) are available
>   for this purpose.

So, suggested method is to write logs to stdout.

Comment: In my opinion all 3 ways are compatible with 11th rule, but: **(1) streams** `+` ensures delivery and allows to use routing, `-` forces to use stream connectors, **(2) log-consuming service**  `+` is easy, `-` logs can be lost and audit biznes info it is too widely propagated - GDPR, **(3) new CF's log type** `-` probably forces changes in the CF.
In my opinion **(1)** is the best choice, please try to convince me.